# AngularJS POST 404

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, http-status-code-404

I am using AngularJS to connect to my service, which is deployed on the same server. I have followed every suggestion listed in all the posts related to similar error, like CORS, but it has not solved my problem. Though, the service is called asynchronously, response is received before the server gets the chance to handle it.
What am I missing?

Here is my service

```
services.factory('TestService', function($http) {
    var myService = {
        createTag: function(tag) {
            return $http.post('/temptag', tag);
        }
    };

    return myService;
});
```

Any my controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('TagCtrl', function ($scope, TestService,$location) {

   $scope.tag={};

    $scope.createTag = function () {

        TestService.createTag($scope.tag).then (function(data){
           console.log('data  Success: = ' + data);
        }, function(data){
            console.log('data = Failure ' + data);

        });

    };
```

});

The control goes to "data Success:" but data is undefined

Comment: Do you get an 404 error code from the server? If so, check which URL you are requesting.

Comment: you are defining `TestService` but using `TagsService` - is it a typo?

Comment: Mikke: Url is right as server handles the request.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo ...fixed

Comment: Please clarify the question, it says the response is returned before the server can handle it? If the server returns a 404, then thats a good place to start.

Comment: Server does not return 404. I put a breakpoint in the server to block the request. But AngularJS assumes that it got 404. If you look at function completeRequest() in angular.js, you would see that it checks for the status. If status == 0, it returns response 404. How does it get status 0?